# SQL Server 2008 R2: Finding cells longer than given number

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table with some records.

**TABLE**:

```
CREATE TABLE TblPatterns
(
    ColPattern VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT INTO TblPatterns VALUES('123A4567890'),
                              ('123B4567890'),
                              ('123A4567891'),
                              ('123A4567892'),
                              ('243C4567890'),
                              ('123A4567890'),
                              ('123'),
                              ('243'),
                              ('123'),
                              ('24'),
                              ('1');
```

I need to write the query to exact match for the given pattern.

The given pattern is like 1 to 10 or 11. What I need to do is, have to check exact 
match of character from LEFT.

Example 1:

```
DECLARE @Pat int = 10
```

Expected Output:

```
ColPattern
---------------
123A4567890
123A4567891
123A4567892
```

Example 2:

```
DECLARE @Pat int = 3
```

Expected Output:

```
ColPattern
---------------
123A4567890
123B4567890
123A4567891
123A4567892
123
243C4567890
243
```

Example 3:

```
DECLARE @Pat int = 1
```

Expected Output:

```
ColPattern
---------------
123A4567890
123B4567890
123A4567891
123A4567892
243C4567890
123
243
24
1
```

**My Try**: 1

```
DECLARE @Pat int = 10

SELECT DISTINCT ColPattern 
FROM TblPatterns
WHERE substring(ColPattern,1,@Pat) IN 
(
    SELECT substring(ColPattern,1,@Pat)
    FROM TblPatterns
    GROUP BY substring(ColPattern,1,@Pat)
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```

But getting unexpected result:

```
ColPattern
------------
123
123A4567890
123A4567891
123A4567892
```

Comment: I am not able to understand from the examples. How pat = 1, matches 243, 24. How pat = 10 matches 123A4567892

Comment: @VenkataramanR, As I said it should match from LEFT, in pat =1 matches found for `243` and `24` because of `2` which is the 1st from left.

Comment: How pat =1, LEFT matches all these patterns. `123A4567890
123B4567890
123A4567891
123A4567892
243C4567890
123
243
24
1`

Comment: @VenkataramanR, Because of `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`.

Comment: If you just remove one of `123`, the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the below logic to get the patterns matching specific length.

```
DECLARE @pat INT = 1
SELECT * from TblPatterns WHERE LEN(colPattern) >= @pat;
```

I have also put [SQLFiddle reference](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/eeabc/6)